# How to execute scroll function every 3 seconds with useEffect React

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am trying to build a component that auto scrolls through some list, forwards and then backwards.

```
  const [clicks, setClicks] = useState(numOfClicks)
  const [goingUp, setGoingUp] = useState(true)

  const scroll = () => {
    if (goingUp) {
      elementsRef.current[current + 1].current.scrollIntoView();
      setCurrent(current + 1);
      setClicks(clicks - 1);
    } else {
      elementsRef.current[current - 1].current.scrollIntoView();
      setCurrent(current - 1);
      setClicks(clicks - 1);
    }
  }
```

if `clicks` reaches 0 the list is at its end and then it flips around and goes backwards until it reaches the start and then the cycle repeats.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (clicks === 0) {
      setGoingUp(!goingUp);
      setClicks(numOfClicks);
    }
  }, [clicks])
```

up to this point, it works fine via click events. My last phase is to execute `scroll` automatically within the component after an interval. For this I use an additional `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      scroll()
    }, TIMER);

    return () => clearInterval(interval); // This represents the unmount function, in which you need to clear your interval to prevent memory leaks.
  }, [])
```

The function runs once and then never again. Although if I add a `console.log` within the effect I see the interval is in fact working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clearInterval` is causing the `setInterval` to stop after `3 sec` , `it only run once` , put your `clearInterval` inside a condition which will specify when you want this to stop

```
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      scroll()
    }, TIMER);

 return () => clearInterval(interval); 

  }, [clicks])
```

Comment: It is not running once if i enter a console.log within the interval it logs correctly continuously

Comment: yeah its because `useEffect` is acting as `componentDidMount` instead it should act as `componentDidUpdate` in your case , for that you need to pass `clicks` in second argument , i will edit the same in provided answer you can refer , hope it works now

Comment: That has indeed solved the issue